# MySQL Innodb phpMyAdmin Mamp

Tags: mysql, wordpress

After working on MAMPPRO on a local WordPress setup I get this message after restarting MAMP. I tried getting the log-file to see what happened.

It really worries me as I think all of my work in the DB is gone.

```
170406 10:53:17 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
170406 10:53:17 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56
2017-04-06 10:53:17 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-04-06 10:53:17 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-04-06 10:53:17 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.35) starting as process 4179 ...
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 18168717 and 18168717 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 18177957 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-04-06 10:53:17 4179 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/slave_worker_info uses space ID: 5 at filepath: ./mysql/slave_worker_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace tandklinik_database/wp_term_taxonomy which uses space ID: 5 at filepath: ./tandklinik_database/wp_term_taxonomy.ibd
2017-04-06 10:53:17 7fffa4a803c0  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./tandklinik_database/wp_term_taxonomy.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170406 10:53:17 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Comment: You have a corrupted database. Follow the suggestion right there in the log. Simple solution would be to restore from the [backup you took yesterday morning before starting any new development](https://media.giphy.com/media/g8A1eJhTQ7Iic/giphy.gif)

Comment: Lol - yes ! the thing is that it happened three times in a week now. There must be something going on.. Is local wordpress development just dodgey? @RiggsFolly

Comment: You’re on a Mac, obviously, so hopefully you’re using Time Machine. In any case, you should locate the folder with the database data. Copy what you’ve got to another folder, and the, as @RiggsFolly suggested restore from your TM backup. I’m not a MAMP user, so I don’t know where to look, but you’re looking for folder with lots of `MYI` and `MYD` files.

Comment: Do you do a clean shutdown of MYSQL before rebooting or doing a ShutDown?

Comment: Still I find it odd that it happens 3 times ..

Comment: I guess I might have restarted the computer without doing a clean shutdown.. that could be it..

Comment: Without buying into the merits of WordPress, one of its (many) issues is maintaining decent copies of the database. I think there are plugins to help you there.

Comment: Yup! Remember this is a serious database manager, not just a file based DB like Access.

Comment: Ok - so the learning is: CLEAN SHUTDOWNS in MAMP pro and backups of database ? anything else ? (thank you so much for fast replies guys! )

Comment: If you don’t do a clean shutdown of the database, a quick fix which _sometimes_ helps is to locate some log files called `ib_logfile*` and delete them.